# Optimizar codigo vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, optimización, microsoft-office, excel-2013

> Necesito optimizar esto

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim fecha As Date, mes As String
    fecha = "1/1/" & Sheets("QUADRANT").Range("A9")
    fechaFin = "31/12/" & Sheets("QUADRANT").Range("A9")
    posA = 0
    modA = 0
    posB = 0
    modB = 0
    posC = 1
    modC = 1
    posD = 0
    modD = 0
    posE = 0
    moddE = 0
    posF = 0
    modF = 0
    For i = fecha To fechaFin

        y = 4 + 7 * Month(i)

        x = 2 + Day(i)
```

> De aqui hasta el final es la parte que mas me interesa

```
        For j = 0 To 5
            If Sheets("QUADRANT").Cells(y + j, x).Value = "R" Then
                If j = 0 Then
                    Sheets("R'S DE TURNOS").Cells(14, 8 + posA).Value = Day(i)
                    posA = posA + 1
                    modA = modA + 1
                    If modA = 5 Then
                        modA = 0
                        posA = posA + 6
                    End If
                ElseIf j = 1 Then
                    Sheets("R'S DE TURNOS").Cells(24, 8 + posB).Value = Day(i)
                    posB = posB + 1
                    modB = modB + 1
                    If modB = 5 Then
                        modB = 0
                        posB = posB + 6
                    End If
                ElseIf j = 2 Then
                    Sheets("R'S DE TURNOS").Cells(34, 8 + posC).Value = Day(i)
                    posC = posC + 1
                    modC = modC + 1
                    If modC = 5 Then
                        modC = 0
                        posC = posC + 6
                    End If
                ElseIf j = 3 Then
                    Sheets("R'S DE TURNOS").Cells(44, 8 + posD).Value = Day(i)
                    posD = posD + 1
                    modD = modD + 1
                    If modD = 5 Then
                        modD = 0
                        posD = posD + 6
                    End If
                ElseIf j = 4 Then
                    Sheets("R'S DE TURNOS").Cells(54, 8 + posE).Value = Day(i)
                    posE = posE + 1
                    moddE = moddE + 1
                    If moddE = 5 Then
                        moddE = 0
                        posE = posE + 6
                    End If
                ElseIf j = 5 Then
                    Sheets("R'S DE TURNOS").Cells(64, 8 + posF).Value = Day(i)
                    posF = posF + 1
                    modF = modF + 1
                    If modF = 5 Then
                        modF = 0
                        posF = posF + 6
                    End If
                End If

            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

End Sub

> (Ignorar) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum tempus nisl sit amet ultrices. Nulla pretium euismod sem, ac vulputate nunc. Aenean sagittis mollis dolor nec gravida.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum tempus nisl sit amet ultrices. Nulla pretium euismod sem, ac vulputate nunc. Aenean sagittis mollis dolor nec gravida.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas interdum tempus nisl sit amet ultrices. Nulla pretium euismod sem, ac vulputate nunc. Aenean sagittis mollis dolor nec gravida.

Comment: Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Publicando en la red [SE] otorgaste derechos no revocables, bajo la [licencia CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) para que SE pueda distribuir su contenido. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/22845).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando haces tareas repetitivas que sólo necesitan cambiar ciertos parámetros lo mejor es sacar esa tarea repetitiva a otro procedimiento y desde el principal llamarlo con argumentos:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim fecha As Date
    'mes As String no se utiliza en todo el código
    fecha = "1/1/" & Sheets("QUADRANT").Range("A9")
    Dim FechaFin As Date
    FechaFin = "31/12/" & Sheets("QUADRANT").Range("A9")
    Dim arrPos As Variant
    arrPos = Array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) 'esto guarda lo que sería los posA-F
    Dim arrMod As Variant
    arrMod = Array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) 'esto guarda lo que sería los modA-F
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim x As Long
    For i = fecha To FechaFin
        y = 4 + 7 * Month(i)
        x = 2 + Day(i)
        For j = LBound(arrMod) To UBound(arrMod)
            If Sheets("QUADRANT").Cells(y + j, x).Value = "R" Then
                VuelcaDatos arrPos, arrMod, Day(i), j, 14 + j * 10
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
Private Sub VuelcaDatos(arrPos As Variant, arrMod As Variant, Dia As Long, j As Long, Fila As Long)
    Sheets("R'S DE TURNOS").Cells(Fila, 8 + arrPos(j)).Value = Dia
    arrPos(j) = arrPos(j) + 1
    arrMod(j) = arrMod(j) + 1
    If arrPos(j) = 5 Then
        arrPos(j) = arrPos(j) + 6
        arrMod(j) = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Acostumbrate a utilizar `Option Explicit` para declarar todas tus variables, y revisa el código porque tienes variables sin utilizar como `mes`.

Answer (score 0):

He eliminado los `Elseif`. En cada comprobación dentro del bucle el valor de la posición de la celda está ligado al valor de j, así que es posible calcularlo con un simple `Cells(14 + (j*10), 8 + posA)`. Es decir `14 + (j*10)`

```
For j = 0 To 5
        If Sheets("QUADRANT").Cells(y + j, x).Value = "R" Then
                Sheets("R'S DE TURNOS").Cells(14 + (j*10), 8 + posA).Value = Day(i)
                posA = posA + 1
                modA = modA + 1
                If modA = 5 Then
                    modA = 0
                    posA = posA + 6
                End If
        End if
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: muchas gracias n